# Getting Selenium to login via .htaccess popup in selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to automate this htaccess popup in selenium  ide. Tried recording it, but was unsuccessful.
Can anyone give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

enter the url in the form username:password@url in you test file

Comment: I did this it worked, but now again getting a confirmation box for OK and cancel after that, which cannot be automated again.

Comment: Yes its a prompt, which is not captured by selenium.